# InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<AliasedClass>'

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a method that takes a query for an object, joins it to a heirarchical table, and from there, joins it to all siblings in a heirarchy. I would like to also add the siblings to the query as SQLAlchemy ORM objects, so that I can retrieve them easily. However, although sqlalchemy allows me to add individual fields from the sibling, adding the alias itself throws an InvalidRequestError.

What is the correct syntax I can use to ask SQLalchemy to return the contents of the sibling alias as full-fledged Thing objects?

```
def siblings( query):
    """query is an already created query with a foreign key to Thing

    Thing has the id field id, and a foreign key named parent_key to Thing"""
    parent = aliased(Thing)
    sibling = aliased(Thing)
    query = query.join(Thing)
    query = query.join(parent, Thing.parent_id==parent.subconstruct_id)
    query = query.join(sibling, sibling.parent_id==parent.id)
    query = query.add_columns(sibling)
    return query
```